# Find the C APIs used for perl script

Tags: perl

Trying to understand the C code that's behind a perl script. For example, the following contrived code:

```
$name = "john";
$greeting = "hi $name, how old are you?";
if ($greeting =~ /hi (\S+)/) {
    $b = $1;
    print "got $b as expected\n";
}
```

Would like to know how the variable $name is substituted in $greeting string, also would like to know what c API is used for the regular expression match.

I heard something like `perl -MO=Bytecode,-H test.pl` where test.pl has the above content, but the output is bindary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a direct mapping of Perl code to C code.  Instead, Perl is a bytecode compiler.  What you can get is the bytecode, the tree of opcodes.  There's several modules to get this in a human readable form, one is [B::Concise](http://metacpan.org/pod/B::Concise).

```
perl -MO=Concise test.pl
```

Produces this...

```
w  <@> leave[1 ref] vKP/REFC ->(end)
1     <0> enter ->2
2     <;> nextstate(main 1 test.plx:1) v:{ ->3
5     <2> sassign vKS/2 ->6
3        <$> const[PV "john"] s ->4
-        <1> ex-rv2sv sKRM*/1 ->5
4           <#> gvsv[*name] s ->5
6     <;> nextstate(main 1 test.plx:2) v:{ ->7
d     <2> sassign vKS/2 ->e
-        <1> ex-stringify sK/1 ->c
-           <0> ex-pushmark s ->7
b           <2> concat[t5] sKS/2 ->c
9              <2> concat[t4] sK/2 ->a
7                 <$> const[PV "hi "] s ->8
-                 <1> ex-rv2sv sK/1 ->9
8                    <#> gvsv[*name] s ->9
a              <$> const[PV ", how old are you?"] s ->b
-        <1> ex-rv2sv sKRM*/1 ->d
c           <#> gvsv[*greeting] s ->d
```

The documentation for B::Concise explains all this.  This tells you the operator sequence, type, name, flags, and the next op in the sequence.  For example...

```
7                 <$> const[PV "hi "] s ->8
```

This is operator 7, it is an SVOP (it applies to scalars), its name is "const" and it's for the scalar string (PV) "hi ", it's in scalar context, and the next operator is 8.

More about operators can be learned from [perlguts](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perl/pod/perlguts.pod) and the [Illustrated Perl Guts](https://github.com/rurban/illguts/blob/master/illguts.pdf?raw=true) and by [poking around in the Perl source code](http://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git).  Each operator has a C function associated with it called `pp_OPNAME` so to find the "const" operator look for `pp_const`.

The Perl regular expression engine is completely custom and has its own [perlreguts](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perl/pod/perlreguts.pod) documentation.